# Problems with setting up MobilePush to App build with React

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, react

We are trying to implement mobile push with application build on React Native. App is installed, SDK is ready, for Android and iOS.

First, contacts were injected anonymously with SFMC generated customer key although we were pushing customer email address as contact key.
When we tried to use the Delay function and first set Contact Key and then enable through SDK, no contacts are passed to Marketing cloud.

Here is the SDK log we get:

```
2020-02-19 13:00:10.565858+0200 Wallet[10206:6406579] [foundation] sfmc_setContactKey xxxxxxxxxxx succeeded

2020-02-19 13:00:19.645073+0200 Wallet[10206:6407320] [foundation] registration json payload is {
"app_version" = "1.0.25";
"device_token" = e5a4def42b9b962a2a843ada66277d6c24e626204afa0799cfe7059917b48989;
deviceid = "41047E00-7053-4B53-A696-C2A136B41983";
dst = 0;
etappid = "a6c24d87-a036-4722-85a8-cf33ba1e5763";
hwid = "iPhone11,2";
locale = "en_BG";
"location_enabled" = 0;
platform = iOS;
"platform_version" = "13.3.1";
"proximity_enabled" = 0;
"push_enabled" = false;
"sdk_version" = "6.4.2";
subscriberKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
tags = (
ALL,
IOS,
iPhone
);
timezone = 7200;
}
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m

2020-02-19 13:00:19.897562+0200 Wallet[10206:6407281] [foundation] registration response: { URL: https://mcck9yhtb4b0v7dr7d76g01ryd4y.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/registration } { Status Code: 201, Headers {
"Cache-Control" = (
"no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
);
Connection = (
"keep-alive"
);
"Content-Length" = (
493
);
"Content-Security-Policy" = (
"upgrade-insecure-requests"
);
"Content-Type" = (
"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
);
Date = (
"Wed, 19 Feb 2020 11:00:19 GMT"
);
"Referrer-Policy" = (
"strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
);
"Strict-Transport-Security" = (
"max-age=15552000; preload"
);
Vary = (
"Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override"
);
"X-Subscriber-Token" = (
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cGUiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NhbGVzZm9yY2UuY29tIiwiY29udGFjdEtleSI6InBsYW1lbkBuZXhvLmlvIiwib3JkaW5hbCI6MSwiZXhwIjoxNTg0NjgwNDE5fQ.zpyLkw_Ip3FSu1d_inLMzCJohaGZBLrG4udfwCSiBws"
);
"x-content-type-options" = (
nosniff
);
"x-frame-options" = (
DENY
);
"x-mashery-message-id" = (
"bfa1b0c4-2744-44df-9059-f176943000c3"
);
"x-mashery-responder" = (
"50-09"
);
"x-xss-protection" = (
"1; mode=block"
);
} }
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 765

2020-02-19 13:00:19.900213+0200 Wallet[10206:6407281] [foundation] registration response generated payloadHash: {length = 20, bytes = 0x253346067c5458d511cad5f787c8dca0f9fb4840}
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
```

And this is the log we get after the app user allows Push notifications

```
2020-02-19 13:04:29.295294+0200 Wallet[10206:6406579] [foundation] device token has been set in the SDK with value: e5a4def42b9b962a2a843ada66277d6c24e626204afa0799cfe7059917b48989
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 1123
2020-02-19 13:04:30.391211+0200 Wallet[10206:6408313] [foundation] push has been enabled in the SDK with value: 0
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 1045
2020-02-19 13:04:32.118345+0200 Wallet[10206:6407725] [foundation] registration key path observer for blob
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 632
2020-02-19 13:04:32.118444+0200 Wallet[10206:6407725] [foundation] push has been enabled in the SDK with value: 1
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 1045
2020-02-19 13:04:32.118525+0200 Wallet[10206:6407725] [foundation] registration key path observer for blob
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 632
```

The wat Contact Key is set is:

```
 MCReactModule.getContactKey()
    .then((key) => {
        console.log('SFMC ContactKey', key);
        if(key !== this.props.profile.email){
            MCReactModule.setContactKey(this.props.profile.email);
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('SFMC ContactKey Error', error)
    })
```

Comment: When you have code involved try to enclosed them with the '{ }' provided in the editor when you post  a question. I have updated your question.

Comment: Thanks, @MinZ, appreciated!

Comment: You managed to successfully "delay contact registration until Contact Key is set", but you do not state anywhere in your question, nor do you show how you're setting the `Contact Key`.

Comment: Hi, @BillMote, I edited the question with the code for setting Contact Key

Comment: Please open a support case through your account representative.

Comment: I did, they told me to better ask the community :-)